Flutter MissingPluginException in second Entrypoint when started from Android FS
I want to develop an Audio Recorder with custom ML models using onnx in Flutter, I am currently targeting Android, and later I want to expand to IOs. In Android I want to run my dart code within the Android Foreground Service. I tried both dart pub.dev plugins, from which I can start the Android FS flutter_foreground_task and flutter_background_service. However, both of them throw a Missing Permission Error from the record plugin, even though I have the permission and can record outside the FS.
Right now I try to do it directly by calling an Android FS using a MethodChannel and then starting an Dart Isolate within the FS. However, when my second entry point gets called it does not have access to my plugins such as permission_handler and record.
This is how I start my DartIsolate from my FS in Kotlin, which works!
private fun startDartIsolate() {

    val loader: FlutterLoader = FlutterInjector.instance().flutterLoader()

    if (!loader.initialized()) {
        loader.startInitialization(applicationContext)
    }

    applicationContext.let { ctx ->
        loader.apply {
            startInitialization(ctx)
            ensureInitializationComplete(ctx, emptyArray<String>())
        }

        flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(ctx, null, false, false)
        flutterEngine?.serviceControlSurface?.attachToService(this, null, true)
        val args: MutableList<String> = MutableList(0) { "" }

        val callbackLibraryPath = null
        val callbackName = "second"

        val entryPoint = DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint(
            loader.findAppBundlePath(),
            callbackName)

        flutterEngine?.getDartExecutor()?.executeDartEntrypoint(entryPoint)
    }

This is my second entry point defined in my main.dart file. It gets called which is great but when using the pmerission_handler or the record plugin it throws this error.
Exception has occurred.
MissingPluginException (MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method checkPermissionStatus on channel flutter.baseflow.com/permissions/methods))

@pragma('vm:entry-point')
void second() async {

    WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
    DartPluginRegistrant.ensureInitialized();

    final microphonePermission = await Permission.microphone.isGranted;
    print("microphonePermission = $microphonePermission");

    final accessNotificationPolicy = await Permission.accessNotificationPolicy.isGranted;
    print("accessNotificationPolicy = $accessNotificationPolicy");

    final notification = await Permission.notification.isGranted;
    print("notification = $notification");

    final record = AudioRecorder();

    final inputDevices = await record.listInputDevices();
    final inputDevice = inputDevices[1];
    print(inputDevice);

    if (await record.hasPermission()) {
      print("Permission granted");
    } else {
      print("Permission denied");
      return;
    }

    final recordConfig = RecordConfig(
        encoder: AudioEncoder.pcm16bits, sampleRate: 16000, numChannels: 1, device: inputDevice); 

    final stream = await record.startStream(recordConfig);
    int counter = 0;

    stream.listen(
      (data) async {
        print(data.elementSizeInBytes);
        counter++;
        if (counter == 100) {
          await record.stop();
        }
      },
      onError: (error) {
        print("onError error = ${error.toString()}");
      },
      onDone: () {
        print("onDone");
      },
    );
  }

To be clear, all the plugins work completely normally, but inside the secondary entry point they don't. If anyone has experience with Flutter and the Android FS and has the time to help me, it would be much appreciated.
I tried all major Flutter plugins for Android FS, and then I switched to the tutorial from:
https://plugfox.dev/android-background-service-with-flutter/
Inside the second entry point from this tutorial, it still throws the Missing Plugin exception.

The MissingPluginException was thrown as I forgot to register the plugins to the FlutterEngine within my ForegroundService.
GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)

And I found out why the record plugin does not grant me permission even though I have permission to record audio. The hasPermission() function checks for an activity which there is non as I start it from an FS.
If I start it without checking with hasPermission() the green microphone notification led gets turned on, however the stream returns nothing.
